# Python - Install keyboard Error - Invalid syntax

Tags: python, pip, keyboard

I was trying to install keyboard in python using python command line but I happen to find an error it in the picture below and that I am a window 7 64bit with python32 and set it up to path.

[image: 1]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+syntaxerror

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to install keyboard in the python console itself. pip does not work in the console itself. Simply close the cmd and open a new one. Type the command there

> pip install keyboard